# How do I print everything separately? What will be the loop?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

Make two new dictionaries representing different people, and store all three 
dictionaries in a list called `people`. Loop through your list of people. As you 
loop through the list, print everything you know about each person.

```
person_1 = {'first_name':'shamol',
      'last_name': 'kabir',
      'age': '25',
      'city': 'jessore'}
person_2 = {'first_name':'shorif',
        'last_name':'jaman',
        'age':'28',
        'city':'khulna'}
person_3= {'first_name':'mizan',
       'last_name':'rahman',
       'age':'25',
       'city':'jessore'}
people= [person_1,person_2,person_3]
```

what will be the next few lines??

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you asking how to iterate over everything? or what else ill be printed out? in python you can just do that by
`for k in dict: print k, dict[k]`

Comment: Heck, you can just `print dict` if you want it to output in that format

Comment: RESULT SHOULD BE LOOK LIKE THIS. BUT CODE SHOULD BE SIMPLE.

first_name:shamol
last_name:kabir
age:25
city:jessore
____________________
first_name:shorif
last_name:jaman
age:28
city:khulna
____________________
first_name:mizan
last_name:rahman
age:25
city:jessore

Answer (score 0):

please first try your self. And this question is pretty simple to find answer.

```
for d in people:
    for key, value in d.items():
        print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are asking for, as you could simply print(people)

```
person_1 = {'first_name':'shamol',
      'last_name': 'kabir',
      'age': '25',
      'city': 'jessore'}
person_2 = {'first_name':'shorif',
        'last_name':'jaman',
        'age':'28',
        'city':'khulna'}
person_3= {'first_name':'mizan',
       'last_name':'rahman',
       'age':'25',
       'city':'jessore'}
people= [person_1,person_2,person_3]

for person in people:
    for key in person:
        print('{} : {}'.format(key, person[key])) # works in both python 2 and python 3
        #print(f'{key} {person[key]}')            #works in python 3 only
    print('-'*20)
```

Comment: that is the answer i am looking for. but is it possible to make it simpler . i dont understand this part "" print('-'*20)""

Comment: it is only to separate data while printing to make more clear, If you wish u can remove it

Comment: just after asked this question. i figured it out why you were using this. it is just underscore multiply 20 times. I can also use it without multiplication but will look bad. I was stupid. long way to go.